# Delayed ObjectNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate

Using: Hibernate 4.2.3, Eclipse Juno and JSR286 portlet

I'm getting an Exception behavior that I don't understand, any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The first time I use a particular database table (which has legacy data) I need to check if a foreign keyed parent record exists, and if it doesn't then I want to insert a dummy parent record, after which time everything will work - I don't want to keep checking for the parent record, so I put in a try/catch block around the statement which will cause an `ObjectNotFoundException` if the parent isn't there.  I know that having a missing parent record causes this Exception, because the error goes away once the parent record is inserted.

The issue I need help with is the Exception is not thrown until **after** exiting the method block and it doesn't get caught by the try/catch block, which is where I need it.

```
public List<Folder> getFolders(Long folderId) {
String hql = "select folder from Folder folder where folder.folderId=:folderId order by folder.folderId";
Boolean valid = false;
List<Folder> folder = new ArrayList<Folder>();
while (!valid) {
  try {
    folder = (List<Folder>) sessionFactory
       .getCurrentSession()
       .createQuery(hql)
       .setLong("folderId", folderId)
       .list();
   valid = true;
} catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) {
try {
    sessionFactory
    .getCurrentSession()
    .createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO `folder` (`folderId`) VALUES (0);")
    .executeUpdate();
    logger.info("added parent record 0 to folder table");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      logger.info(e1.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
return folder;
```

}

**EDIT:**
here's the stack trace - as you can see Hibernate throws a warning, then the next error comes from Spring DispatcherPortlet, not from any of my own code.

```
2013-10-20 23:15:07,438 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadContexts] - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@a5571f9<rs=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet@417e79d3>
2013-10-20 23:15:07,438 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] - HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries
2013-10-20 23:15:07,438 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadContexts] - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@6fad97bb<rs=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet@5d4fab2d>
2013-10-20 23:15:07,438 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] - HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries
2013-10-20 23:15:07,438 WARN [org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet] - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.sbeko.slider.domain.Folder#10207]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
```

Comment: So where IS it thrown?  Java exceptions usually come with a stack trace, they give the line at which the exception occurred.  Where is that?  What code is executing at the time the exception happens?

Comment: It is thrown outside any of the code that I've written, which means I can't AFAIK gracefully catch it.

Answer (score 1):

From the Hibernate ObjectNotFoundException javadoc:

> Thrown when Session.load() fails to select a row with the given
>   primary key (identifier value). This exception might not be thrown
>   when load() is called, even if there was no row on the database,
>   because load() returns a proxy if possible. Applications should use
>   Session.get() to test if a row exists in the database.

So there are two things to check: if you have lazy instantiation, and are therefore getting a proxy instead of a real object and getting the exception at the point where the real object is actually used, and whether session.get() will either solve your problem or even serve your purpose better.

---

edit to handle further questions:

found this in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221514/hibernate-check-if-object-exists), using HQL:

```
public Boolean exists (DTOAny instance) 
{
    Query query = getSession().             
    createQuery("select 1 from DTOAny t where t.key = :key");
        query.setString("key", instance.getKey() );
    return (query.uniqueResult() != null);
}
```

You would replace `instance.getKey()` with whatever you need to get the ID of the instance you're trying to find.

Also, if you're going to use the get() method you mention, I think it needs the actual index ID, not 0.  Good luck.

Comment: rcook - many thanks, but unless I'm misunderstanding something, the problem is that .get() relates to session and not .createQuery().list() as I have -  the problem is that the parent row I'm trying to create won't exist until it's created by the exception, what do I get?. Any chance you could give me an example how I'd use .get(folder.class, ?) in my situation?

Comment: I've tried sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Folder.class, 0L), but that doesn't throw the Exception either, at least not until afterwards.  So maybe something's corrupted in my compiler or one of the Spring or Hibernate Libraries, what do you think?