# Can't catch exception from Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
ClientEntity clientEntity;
try {
    clientEntity = entityManager.getReference(ClientEntity.class, clientId);
}
catch (EntityNotFoundException ex){
    System.out.println("Wrong client id: there are no client with such id.");
    return;
}
```

I sent the wrong parameter value. In the database there is certainly no such client (with id = 6, for example). But `catch {}` didn't work.

From `getReference` docs:

> If the requested instance does not exist in the database, the
>   EntityNotFoundException is thrown when the instance state is first
>   accessed. (The persistence provider runtime is permitted to throw the
>   EntityNotFoundException when getReference is called.)

But in the debugger we can see that `EntityNotFoundException` occurs.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: debugger]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss this

> the EntityNotFoundException is thrown when the instance state is first accessed

You don't access the entity state in your code.

A debugger access the entity to show it properties.

`getReference()` is not a suitable method to check entity existence.

You can use something like this (need to be rewritten for JPA):
[Hibernate: check if object exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404799/3405171)

Comment: This caught me as well.